# Splitting multiple character vectors in a data frame efficiently in R

Tags: r, strsplit

Perhaps this is being a bit picky, but I'd like to come up with an elegant way to split multiple columns of strings in a data frame. For example, I often receive data from Excel where the units are in the same cells as the values, like this:

```
df <- data.frame(A = paste(round(runif(5) * 10), "KG", sep = " "), 
             B = paste(round(runif(5) * 10), "KG", sep = " "), 
             C = paste(round(runif(5) * 10), "KG", sep = " "))
df
     A    B     C
1 1 KG 9 KG  7 KG
2 8 KG 1 KG 10 KG
3 7 KG 8 KG  6 KG
4 5 KG 6 KG  9 KG
5 3 KG 2 KG  9 KG
```

From here, the units need to be separated and stored. Typically, I do something like this:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, 
    function(x) as.numeric(lapply(strsplit(as.character(x), 
    split = " ", fixed = TRUE), "[", 1))))

df3 <- as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, 
    function(x) as.character( lapply(strsplit(as.character(x),
    split = " ", fixed = TRUE), "[", 2))))

df4 <- cbind(df2, df3)
df4
  A B  C  A  B  C
1 1 9  7 KG KG KG
2 8 1 10 KG KG KG
3 7 8  6 KG KG KG
4 5 6  9 KG KG KG
5 3 2  9 KG KG KG
```

It works, but is a hassle to implement. Is there a better solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` it together and read with `read.table`

```
read.table(text=do.call(paste, df), sep="", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#1  4 KG  0 KG  6 KG
#2  2 KG  5 KG  4 KG
#3  4 KG 10 KG  1 KG
#4  9 KG  4 KG  7 KG
#5  1 KG  9 KG  5 KG
```

---

Another option is `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df, names(df), " ")
```

NOTE: The values are different as `set.seed` was not called by the OP.

Comment: That's far quicker and less complicated. Thanks!